# JQuery check multiple checkbox's within a table row

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have HTML as below:

```
<tr class="gridSubHeader1">
<td colspan="6"><input type="checkbox" familyname="TestName" onclick="javascript: HandleClick('TestName');">EB - Autonomy</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000748" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">1&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000749" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">2&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000750" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">3&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="237" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">4&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>

<tr class="gridSubHeader1">
<td colspan="6"><input type="checkbox" familyname="TestName2" onclick="javascript: HandleClick('TestName2');">EB - Another</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000748" id="TestName2">
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">1&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000749" id="TestName2">
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">2&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000750" id="TestName2">
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">3&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="237" id="TestName2">
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">4&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
```

there could be multiple rows, with row representing a particular family. see the above, there are 2 families, TestName and TestName 2. Each can have one or more checkbox's with each row.

script code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function HandleClick(elementName) {
         if ($("input[familyname='" + elementName + "']").is(':checked')) {
            $("#" + elementName).each(function () {
                $(this).find('input', 'checkbox').attr('checked', true);
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#" + elementName).each(function () {
                $(this).find('input', 'checkbox').attr('checked', false);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

It seems to select only the first checkbox, instead of selecting all the 4. Can you suggest what is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

**ID** in a HTML page is **unique**..

So when you are trying to select Multiple id's , because the ID is unique , it stops the search after encountering the first ID element.. That's the reason only the first is being checked

So you need to modify you selector.. Also you do not need the $.each iterator to get this working .. try this

```
$(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').prop('checked', true);
```

Try this code..
**JS**

```
var elementName = 'TestName' ;
$('input[familyname="TestName"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($("input[familyname='" + elementName + "']").is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').prop('checked', true);

    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').prop('checked', false);
    }
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1">
      <td colspan="6"><input type="checkbox" familyname="TestName" />EB - Autonomy</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000748">
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">1&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000749">
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">2&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000750">
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">3&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="237">
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">4&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

`I have removed the ID from your table`. Make sure they are Unique on the page

Also this line can be

```
if ($("input[familyname='" + elementName + "']").is(':checked'))
```

**// replaced with**

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

**[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/macTj/1/)**

**EDITED**

This is the code with the eventHandler defined in the HTML itself..

```
<table>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1">
      <td colspan="6"><input type="checkbox" familyname="TestName" onclick="javascript:HandleClick('TestName');" />EB - Autonomy</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000748">
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">1&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000749">
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">2&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000750">
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">3&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="237">
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">4&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" id="Select" name="Select" unchecked="" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function HandleClick(elementName) {
       var $checkBox = $("input[familyname='" + elementName + "']") ;
       if ($checkBox.is(':checked')) {
            $checkBox.closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').prop('checked', true);
       }
       else {
          $checkBox.closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').prop('checked', false);
       }
   }
</script>​
```

Comment: I have edited the post that includes the handler in html.. Check edit

Comment: your second edit seems to work. but its selecting all the families, including checkbox's that are outside

Comment: You are using this in your code, which references the window object.. I have included that in the code

Comment: If you are using jquery to define the event then you can use this,, but when you call a function from HTML , this is the window object

Comment: Edited my original HTML. there cud be multiple families. Your most recent solution works, but its selecting all checkbox's instead of just its families checkbox's. See my edited HTML above.

Comment: If that's the case instead of giving your checkbox's id give it the same class name class="TestName" class="TestName2"

Comment: Your selector will then be $checkBox.closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input.' + elementName).prop('checked', true);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I cannot add a class to that inner checkbox element as I don't have much control over that part of the HTML. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: Then where are you adding the id from

Comment: id is something is coming along with the rest of the HTML

Comment: Is the number of rows to be checked in each frame is always 4

Answer (score 0):

I recreated it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjoshuanoah/Rsasf/

replace id's with classes for something that is used multiple times.

Oh, and unless you ABSOLUTELY need too, please don't code in tables.... 8\

This works:

```
<tr class="gridSubHeader1">
<td colspan="6"><input type="checkbox" familyname="TestName">EB - Autonomy</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000748" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">1&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" class="TestName" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000749" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">2&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" class="TestName" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="1000750" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="20">3&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyOddRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" class="TestName" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridSubHeader1" rowID="237" id="TestName">
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="20">4&nbsp;</td>
<td class="formBodyEvenRow" width="30"><input type="Checkbox" class="TestName" name="Select" unchecked=""></td>
</tr>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With the JS:

```
var handleClick = function(elementName) {
         if ($("input[familyname='" + elementName + "']").is(':checked')) {
            $("input." + elementName).each(function () {
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
            });
        }
        else {
            $("input." + elementName).each(function () {
                 console.log('tr'); 
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            });
        }
}

$('input[familyname="TestName"]').click(function(){
    handleClick('TestName');
});
```

​

Comment: If this were data, I'd agree. :) however, this seems to be a roundabout way of aligning checkboxes that could be done with css.

Comment: I agree, but this is the HTML that I receive, I don't have total control over it to change it. I can consume it only and have to write jquery using it.

Comment: Gotcha. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Please take a look at my recent edit, i updated the HTML to reflect the changes.